# Define a Cross-origin Property

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

TL;DR: Is it possible to define a cross-origin property on a parent window to act as flag accessible to a child window?

I have a JavaScript application that may be run in an iframe or top-level browsing context. When in an iframe, the application will attempt to query a feature in the parent window using window.postMessage. This feature may not exist, so I encapsulated window.postMessage and implemented a timeout. However, the timeout has to be quite long, and this has a negative impact on the load time when the feature does not exist. Is it possible to define a cross-origin property on the parent window to act as flag to replace the timeout?

```
var parent = window.parent;
if (parent && parent.hasFeature) {
    window.postMessage(...);
    return;
}
...
```

I didn't see any support provided by the access descriptor for [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), and it looks like the [cross-origin property descriptor map](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#shared-internal-slot:-crossoriginpropertydescriptormap) is internal.

Comment: Can't you just post a message and see if you get a return one? Would require parent to be listening for it and send response.

Comment: Why do you use a long timeout? Responding to `postMessage` should be pretty fast.

Comment: The application needs to know if the feature is available before it becomes available to the user, and there is a case where the parent won't respond. Originally, the timeout was 100 ms. However, in testing I have had to increase it to ~400 ms which is a noticeable and guaranteed delay in load time when the feature doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a way to define a cross-origin property on a window. I don't think its possible. However, I did discover three ways to pass data between windows with different origins without using a Web request or postMessage.

1. If the parent has control of the child's location, include data as query
   parameters that the child will check for. Note, that the parameter
   will also be passed to the server. See the following example.

   *http://host/index.html?flag=1*
2. If the parent has control of the child's location, include data as
   the hash fragment that the child will check for. This is more
   appropriate than a query parameter, because the hash fragment is
   meant to be used for client data. However, it may not be an option
   if the client uses the hash fragment for navigation.

   *http://host/index.html*#flag=1
3. Include data as the [name of the iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#name-attribute). The initial name of the
   iframe defines the name of the embedded browsing context which can
   be accessed by the child with [window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name). However, this is not
   the intended use of window.name and may break or be broken by other
   functionality.

   ```
   <iframe name="flag=1" src="http://host"></iframe>
   ```